# Subset a dataframe using dateInput values as range in shiny

Tags: date, shiny, reactive

Hello I have a simple shiny app below. Here is the `df`:

```
location = c("100 ail","16th and Whitmore","40AB01 - ANTWERPEN","100 ail","16th and Whitmore","40AB01 - ANTWERPEN") 
date = c("2015-09-01 00:00:00","2016-03-06 19:00:00","2016-11-22 15:00:00","2018-02-01 09:30:00", "2018-02-01 03:00:00", "2017-03-07 10:00:00") 
pm25=c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE")
pm10=c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE")
no2=c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE")
latitude=c(47.932907,41.322470,36.809700,47.932907,41.322470,36.809700)
longitude=c(106.92139000,-95.93799000
            ,-107.65170000,106.92139000,-95.93799000
            ,-107.65170000)

df = data.frame(location, date,latitude,longitude,pm25,pm10,no2)
```

and the app:

```
ui = fluidPage(

  uiOutput("dt"),
  uiOutput("dt2"),
  submitButton(text = "Submit", icon = NULL, width = NULL),
  shiny::dataTableOutput("merged") 
)

#server.r

#df$location <- gsub( " " , "+" , df$location)
server = function(input, output, session) {







  output$dt<-renderUI({

    dateInput('date',
              label = 'First Available Date',
              value = df$date
    )           


  })
  output$dt2<-renderUI({

    dateInput('date2',
              label = 'Last available Date',
              value = df$date
    )            


  })
  output$merged <- shiny::renderDataTable({
    df %>%
      filter(date >= input$dt & date <= input$dt2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The df I want to display as datatable should take as inputs tha dates provided by the 2 `selectInput()` as range and changes its appearance everytime they are updated. Can this be done? Or `dateInput()` just displays the data that it takes from the beginning and cannot be used for subsetting?

Comment: it might be related to a date issue.

Comment: I could place a \ between date time instead of " " but that would change the date format and could not be read by dateInput. Maybe it is because the dateInput take as inputs values from the df and cannoy use these values to update itself. I m stuck

Comment: In general what im trying to do is subset the dataframe with options that are created by itself. Its like a circle. Or the dateInput cant be used for this kind of task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to convert your `date` column to `date` format. (I used `lubridate` for this purpose.

```
library(lubridate)

df = data.frame(location, date = as_datetime(date),latitude,longitude,pm25,pm10,no2)
```

The usage of `renderUI` is not needed in this case, since your data is not dynamic. (It works like this as well, just not ideal). I would just simply use `dateInput`:

```
dateInput('date',
            label = 'First Available Date',
            value = min(df$date)
)   ,
dateInput('date2',
          label = 'Last available Date',
          value = max(df$date)
)
```

Also, for `dateInput` setting `value = df$date` results in a warning, since the `value` argument takes a single value, but `df$date` is a `vector` of length 6. So instead I changed it to `min(df$date)` and `max(df$date)`.

In your `render` function you need to specify the `id`s of the `dateInput`s, so use `input$date` and `input$date2` instead of `dt` and `dt2`.

Note: when using *dplyr* `filter`: the operator `&` is not needed, you can just separate your filtering conditions with a comma.

```
df %>%
      filter(as_date(date) >= input$date, as_date(date) <= input$date2)
```

One more thing: I opted to convert `date_time` to `date` using `as_date(date)` for filtering. If you compare `date`s with `date_time` you might get unexpected results, like `2017-03-12 02:00` is greater than `2017-03-02`.

### Complete code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

df = data.frame(location, date = as_datetime(date),latitude,longitude,pm25,pm10,no2)

ui = fluidPage(
  dateInput('date',
            label = 'First Available Date',
            value = min(df$date)
  )   ,
  dateInput('date2',
            label = 'Last available Date',
            value = max(df$date)
  ),
  submitButton(text = "Submit", icon = NULL, width = NULL),
  shiny::dataTableOutput("merged") 
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$merged <- shiny::renderDataTable({
    df %>%
      filter(as_date(date) >= input$date, as_date(date) <= input$date2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you can just use a single `dateRangeInput` here and access both values with `input$date[1]` and `input$date[2]`

Comment: Actually my real data is dynamic(not this one) so i guess i should remain wth input$dt,input$dt2?

Comment: even if that's the case you can refer to the values as `input$date` and `input$date2`. The values are not passed on to `uiOutput`.